# How to return from a SQL function that includes a recursive common table expression?

Tags: sql-function

I have a function like this (just reduced it in order to make it readable ):

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunction(somearg text) RETURNS integer AS
$$
WITH recursive mycte(index, myi) AS (
    select 0,null
    --from
    --where

    UNION ALL
        
    SELECT mycte.index+1, case when[condition] then mycte.myi=mycte.index end
    FROM mytable AS m, mycte
    WHERE   index<50

)
SELECT myi
FROM mycte;
--how to return myi;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL ;

SELECT myfunction('abc');
```

How can I return myi?

Once `[condition]` is true, `myi` should be returned. (`[condition]` can be true only once in my task and efficiency is no problem)

Comment: You need to add some means (`WHERE` clause, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`) to the outer query limiting the number of records in the result set to (the) one (you want).

Comment: it can be only one and I want that one. Nevertheless I tried ORDER BY myi desc LIMIT 1; but that does not help

Comment: Your edit suggests that you could your condition as a column of the CTE and a `WHERE` to the outer query demanding this column to be `true`.

Comment: Some more details, especially a [example] would help to understand what you have and want though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "return" anything. The result of a SQL function is automatically the last query in the body. In your case it's the "main" select of the CTE.

If the function is declared as a scalar function (as yours is), this also means only the "first" row of the result will be returned.

The way you call it will work just fine.

But given your query, I think your function should be declared as `returns table (myi integer)`

Comment: Thanks for Your help. I return an integer because it could only happen once that the condition for myi=... happens. Therefore, I am 'searching' for an integer to return. Otherwise, I would do: ...then sth || mycte.index || sthdiff ...

Comment: Well, that's what your function does